# Not sure why I'm getting an error of "Value of property VPCSecurityGroups must be of type List of String"

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error that reads "Value of property VPCSecurityGroups must be of type List of String"

I've tried creating a db instance in cloud formation. The name of the security group is: wordpressDBSecurityGroup. I've tried passing the value to the db instance in the following ways:

I tried using FN::GetAtt

```
"VPCSecurityGroups" : {
                "Fn::GetAtt": 
                [
                "wordpressDBSecurityGroup", 
                "GroupId"]
            }
```

I also tried hard coding the name into the attribute:

```
"VPCSecurityGroups": "wordpressDBSecurityGroup"
```

I also tried using the 'Ref' functionality:

```
"VPCSecurityGroups" : {"Ref": "wordpressDBSecurityGroup"}
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error? How should I be doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the brackets to the ref functionality. This fixed the issue.

```
"VPCSecurityGroups" : [{"Ref": "wordpressDBSecurityGroup"}]
```